# Iframe child sending data to parent and clearingtimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, settimeout, colorbox

Hi Teams from all around,

I am most stumped on this issue.

I am attempting to use color box to create a pop up of a url through an iframe. (please not that the creative and source I have are the test pages, not actual subject). I am looking to have the iframe close after 12 seconds unless someone click within the iframe on the images within.

Basically it is a floater that will be for things such as group newsletters. I want to be able to just switch out the source page and have it available when the page first loads.

So, the page loads, starts the iframe floater, closes after (x) seconds unless someone clicks anywhere on the iframe, at that point they have to hit the close button.

I have been working on this for 2 days, and I either have it where the floater does not close at all or the floater refuses to stay open.

Please help.

And Much thanks in advance.

**Preview Page:**

```
http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/TestPageSETUP.html
```

**Code on Parent Page:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/colorbox.css">
<script src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script>
Var t;
window.onload =  $(document).ready(function(){
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"95%", height:"95%", open:true, opacity:.2, overlayClose:false, escKey:false, closeButton:true, reposition:true});
});

</script><script>

window.onload =  $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
t = setTimeout($.colorbox.close, 12000);
});

</script><script>
 $(".iframe").click(function(){
 alert("click");
 clearTimeout(t);
 };
 </script>

<a class='iframe' href="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/testPageA.html"></a>
```

**Code on Child Page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').click(function(){
    parent.postMessage('alert','moooo');
});
</script>

<img src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/imgCreativeContent/imgExpanded/creative/grassSet3.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I actually was semi close before.
Here is how I did it. I am leaving this here for future people to learn from and have a very easy time.

Allowing the future web developers to learn.

**Parent:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/colorbox.css">
<script src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/images/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script>
var t;

var iframeHost = "http://matthewsallansdesign.com"

if(typeof window.postMessage != 'undefined'){
var iframeListener = function (event) {
console.log(event);
        if(iframeHost == event.origin){
clearTimeout(t);
        }
    }      
if (window.addEventListener) {
      addEventListener("message", iframeListener, false);
    }       
else {
      attachEvent("onmessage", iframeListener);
    }
}


window.onload =  $(document).ready(function(){
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"95%", height:"95%", open:true, opacity:.2, overlayClose:false, escKey:false, closeButton:true, reposition:true});
});

window.onload =  $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
t = setTimeout($.colorbox.close, 6000);
});

</script>

<a class='iframe' href="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/Scripps/testPageA.html"></a>
```

**Child:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').click(function(){
parent.postMessage("HAMPSTERS",'*');
});
</script>

<img src="http://matthewsallansdesign.com/imgCreativeContent/imgExpanded/creative/grassSet3.png">
```

The only thing anyone needs to actually do with this is replace the urls above.

I recommend everyone download the js and css on their own servers.
I will leave it up so others can find it.

Thanks,
Matthew